# What to do if Windows Update constantly fails without error code?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, updates, windows-update

What can I do to get my Windows XP (currently SP2) up to date when my Windows Update constantly fails without error code? (Just telling me the updates haven't been installed.)

It doesn't matter if I try to update using the built in Windows Update or the update website.
As well there's no difference wether I try to install SP3 or install the other updates manually.

Comment: Check the eventlog -> Setup & System section. To open the eventlog, open the run prompt and type "eventvwr". Let us know if you see any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try these things:

0)
Reboot. Then try again. (The reason behind this is that previously applied windows updates might block other windows updates until the host has restarted.

1)
Check for error message in `WindowsUpdate.log` (This file is usually found in c:\windows).  Then check the event logs `eventvwr.msc`)
If it has a error, act on it, if not go to 2)

2)
Log in with an administrative account.
[start] [run] [cmd]
type `net stop wuauserv`
(leave the prompt open)

Go to %windir&\SoftwareDistribution (Usually `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\`.
Delete everything.  (You can do this because the windows update service is stopped).
Go back to the open cmd prompt and enter `net start wuauserv`.
(Some files will not reappear in the SoftwareDistribution folder.)

Try windows update again.

3)
If it still fails go to another computer and download a liveCD.
Boot from the CD and check the computer for a virus and or a root kit. (Some of these block windows updates).
[This post on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now/157533#157533) has a lot of information in this.

Comment: hint #2 worked very well, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason for Windows Update to fail is that you have a backlog of several updates that can't all be installed together.  If you haven't already done this, try applying the updates one-at-a-time, starting with the oldest (lowest numbered).